# Xamarin VS Mac dreaded MSB6002 Error

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

I am working on an iOS and Droid app using Xamarin.Forms (2.5.1.444934). The build environment is OSX 10.13.4, VS for Mac 7.4.3 (Build 10), and Xcode 9.3 (9E145). The project is Xamarin Forms using Standard .NET 2.0.1 library for the shared code. I have an additional shared Standard .NET 2.0.1 library for code shared with the backend.

I was building ok and then made some changes to Xamarin.Auth (v1.6.0.2). I started getting several warnings. The first is /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(3,3): Warning MSB6002: The command-line for the "MTouch" task is too long. Command-lines longer than 32000 characters are likely to fail. Try reducing the length of the command-line by breaking down the call to "MTouch" into multiple calls with fewer parameters per call. (MSB6002)

Followed by 3 MTouch Warnings

- /MTOUCH: Warning MT0127:
  Incremental builds have been disabled because this version of
  Xamarin.iOS does not support incremental builds in projects that
  include more than one third-party binding libraries. (MT0127)
- /MTOUCH: Warning MT3005:
  The dependency 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' of the assembly 'InnerCircle,
  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' was not found.
  Please review the project's references. (MT3005)
- /MTOUCH: Warning MT3006: 
  Could not compute a complete dependency map for the project. This will result in slower build times because Xamarin.iOS can't properly detect what needs to be rebuilt (and what does not need to be rebuilt). Please review previous warnings for more details. (MT3006)

I also got a warning I have never seen - /obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.5-11.3/mtouch-cache/registrar.m(2,2): Warning G3CD13281: method possibly missing a [super viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange] call [-Wobjc-missing-super-calls] (G3CD13281)

I ran the build however when I go to Save to the secure store I get an exception.

```
        Account _account = new Account
        {
            Username = username
        };
        _account.Properties.Add(nameof(password), password);
        _account.Properties.Add(nameof(token), token);
        _account.Properties.Add(nameof(hasProfileImage), hasProfileImage.ToString());
        AccountStore.Create().Save(_account, App.AppName);
```

{Xamarin.Auth.AccountStoreException: SaveAsync error = Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: stringToEscape
  at Xamarin.Auth.KeyChainAccountStore.SaveAsync (Xamarin.Auth.Account account, System.String serviceId) [0x00140] in <5426a6dbbfb9439a9005b7bf164bb3d1>:0 
  at Xamarin.Auth.KeyChainAccountStore.Save (Xamarin.Auth.Account account, System.String serviceId) [0x00000] in <5426a6dbbfb9439a9005b7bf164bb3d1>:0 
  at Services.AzureSecurityService.SaveAccount (System.String username, System.String password, System.String token, System.Boolean hasProfileImage) [0x0004b] in /Users/rsatter/Projects/InnerCircle/Apps/InnerCircle/Services/AzureSecurityService.cs:209 
  at Services.AzureSecurityService+d__9.MoveNext () [0x001e7] in /Users/rsatter/Projects/InnerCircle/Apps/InnerCircle/Services/AzureSecurityService.cs:128 }

I have not a clue what is wrong or where to start. I had the code working earlier before I moved the code and add token and hasProfileImage to the properties.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of App.AppName when you run the program?